# Display MPAndroidChart PieChart horizontally

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

Is there a chart that looks like PieChart and rather than circle, numbers should be displayed in horizontal bar?

In PieChart, we display numbers in Circle. But how can i display them in single bar(horizontal)?

Anybody can help here?

I need a horizontal chart for this PieChart
[image]

I tried updating my code to have horizontalbarchar and got below chart. But the values are showing wrong in the chart and also i dont want to show the other parameters which are marked in Red. Can someone help me here.

My Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.HorizontalBarChart
        android:id="@+id/chart1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

My code:

```
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.horizontal_seekbar_layout);
        mChart = findViewById(R.id.chart1);

        ArrayList<BarEntry> values=new ArrayList<>();
        values.add(new BarEntry(0,new float[]{5,3,1}));

        BarDataSet set1=new BarDataSet(values,"Summary");
        //set1.setDrawIcons(false);
        set1.setStackLabels(new String[]{"Passed","Failed","Skipped"});
        ArrayList<Integer> colors=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        colors.add(Color.GREEN);
        colors.add(Color.RED);
        colors.add(Color.GRAY);
        set1.setColors(colors);
        set1.setValueFormatter(new DecValueFormatter());

        BarData data=new BarData(set1);
        mChart.setData(data);
       // mChart.setFitBars(true);
        mChart.invalidate();
```

My current chart i am getting:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done using stacked bar chart of mp android chart. Please follow example below to do that:

```
ArrayList<BarEntry> barEntries = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
    barEntries.add(new BarEntry(0, new float[]{2,4,5,3}));


    BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(barEntries, "Stacked Bars");
    barDataSet.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
    barDataSet.setHighlightEnabled(true);
    barDataSet.setHighLightColor(Color.RED);
    barDataSet.setColors(getColors(4,Color.RED,Color.BLUE,Color.GREEN,Color.CYAN));
    barDataSet.setStackLabels(new String[]{"Bottom","Top","Left","Right"});

    BarData barData = new BarData(barDataSet);
    barData.setValueTextSize(defaultValueTextSize);
    barData.setValueTextColor(getColor("primaryDark"));

    barChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(false); // add this line to show values inside bars
    barChart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMinimum(0);
    barChart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTH_SIDED);
    barChart.animateY(1000);
    barChart.setData(barData);
```

This is for vertical bar just use horizontal bar chart of this library and you are good to go with buddy. Happy Coding :)

Comment: I tried above said sample code and now endup with above picture. Can you please tell me, why in the chart wrong values are show. Ex. the green color portion should show 5, red 3 and grey 1. And also how to not show the one with red color marks in above chart? Also sharing the code which i tried. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I edited the answer and commented to add the line... Add that line to your code.

Comment: I edited the answer and commented to add the line... Add that line to your code.

Comment: Thanks that worked. Initially i thought of array index problem in this line, values.add(new BarEntry(0,new float[]{5,3,1})); But your added line helped me. Is there a way that i can eliminate the extra lines shown(marked in Red) in my above bar chart?